# How do I import jhipster project into intellij?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, jhipster

I have a jhipster project I want to import into IntelliJ Ultimate latest version 2016.3.2. The problem is, after I run my yo jhipster command, when I try to "Import from Existing Project" in IntelliJ 2016, after I select "Maven Project", its not letting me hit the next button to get past that dialogue box. I am running Windows. What is going on?

What is the proper way to import this project??? The youtube video they have on their main site is outdated and does not work at all.

Comment: Is there an existing pom.xml file you can import?

Comment: Yes, by default the jhipster root directory of my project has a pom.xml file.

Comment: Not sure. I just imported a Maven project today.

Comment: Can you try using jhipster to generate a project and attempt import? i have no problems with Maven, just jhipster generated projects using Windows.https://jhipster.github.io

Comment: There's nothing special to do, it's a maven project. I just tried and it worked fine on Windows. BTW, it's "import project from external model" at least in 2017 EAP. Then follow instructions on https://jhipster.github.io/configuring-ide-idea/

Comment: Also, I don't see what is outdated regarding IDEA setup in our video tutorial https://jhipster.github.io/video-tutorial/

Answer (score 2):

To start a #Jhipster Maven project on Intellij Community (ver 2017.3.3) :

1 start intellij community

2 import the maven project (if you havent done so already), as explained here:
[check out the section: Importing a Maven project](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/maven.html)

3 create a MAVEN configuration by :

- go to the edit configuration option, in the drop down on the top toolbar:

[image]

- then press the green + (plus sign) and choose MAVEN from the vertical toolbar
  on the left
  Set a meaningful name in the NAME field  and point the working directory to the folder of your project's POM.xml. Press OK

[image]

4. you will see the name you gave in the previous stem on the drop down mentioned in step 2 (select from the drop down it if it is not already selected)
   then press the RUN button to the right (a Green "play" button).

**This will run your project**

**HOWEVER, it will not necessarily run the FRONT-END angular app.**

**To run the angular client :** open a terminal (CMD on windows) and go to the base folder of your jhipster project.

Then type:

> **yarn start**

(This should start your frontend)